# Como obter e modificar uma requisição do AJAX?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão, xmlhttprequest

Eu estou criando um complemento para estudo próprio para o *Chrome*, no complemento eu modifico várias partes de um site.
Mas agora eu preciso modificar uma requisição `ajax`, o site faz a solicitação antes do script da extensão entrar em ação.
Eu já fiz algo semelhante mas em *localhost*, eu utilizei `XMLHttpRequest` para capturar todas as requisições *ajax* e modifica-las numa função.

Mas no *Chrome*, não sei como fazer pra extensão capturar a requisição **"/evento/original/"** e fazer o `return` de **"meusite.com/meuscript.php?ul=/evento/original/"**

Como eu capturo uma requisição `ajax` e a retorno modificada para o site remoto?